# Does Javascript SDK update accessToken expiry?

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-oauth

Sorry if this a simple uber basic question... but I am just looking for clarification.

If our pages are calling the Facebook Javascript SDK () on most pages, is the expiration of the accessToken being refreshed and updated when the SDK is called?

I noticed that if I am always opening pages on our site that make the SDK call, then the accessToken does not seem to need refreshing.  However if I leave the computer for more than 2 hours and do not refresh the page or open other pages that make the call during that time.  After returning to the computer and reloading a page I get the accessToken expired error.

So does the accessToken expire only if a call to the SDK does not happen for more than the default 2 hours?

Cheers